# Function won't to return array

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

Here I have a function `nArray`. This function must return bigArray (JSON objects), but function doesn't return bigArray...

http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/29/

```
function nArray() {

//CODE IS HERE

        return bigArray;
}
console.log(nArray);
$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(nArray, null, 4));
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by not actually calling your function...face palm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling your function. Do this:

```
console.log(nArray());
//                ^^-----------note the parentheses
$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(nArray(), null, 4));
//                                 ^^-----------and here
```

Regarding your fiddle, I don't see any `<pre>` elements in it, so that last line of code that tries to set the `.html()` of a `$('pre')` isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

`nArray` is a function, so you need to execute it by adding parenthesis:

```
console.log(nArray());
$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(nArray(), null, 4));
```

At the moment, you're just passing a reference to the function.